# Deploying MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, .net-4.0

I'm using VS2010 and I'm deploying my MVC3 app to my webserver. I went to Project->Publish settings and added my database connection and thats it. I right clicked on my application and clicked "Build deployment package" which generated a zip file. I copied it to my server and imported the application into IIS with no errors. But when I try to load it in a browser I get the dreaded :

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies

I took that line out of web.config, then i got:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies

I took that line out of web.config, then i got:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies

Need i continue? What am i doing wrong when I deploy or build my application to load it into IIS so all dependencies are avaiable?

.NET 4.0 is the default app pool in IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add deployable dependencies by right-clicking project and selecting "Add Deployable Dependencies".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg286946.aspx

Note that it requires Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 or later versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: I have vs2010 sp1 and I added deployable dependencies. Now i get this: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. It found the other assemblies

Comment: I deleted the bin_deployableableAssemblies folder, then readded it, now it cant find System.Web.WebPages. any other suggestions?

Comment: Setup a new project and did the exact same steps now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't take those lines out of Web.config.

Instead, set the references to `Copy Local` and re-deploy.

Comment: I tried that and I still get the same errors. My test site is http://66.23.236.202/Telerik. I even see the dlls in the bin folder